# How to Solve this Coupled ODE-PDE System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The system of coupled PDE-ODE has been stumping me for how they get their resulting solutions. The paper I'm referencing has the equations as shown below. I'm unsure how they got their solutions and need guidance for how they arrived at their final functions.

If there's a way to solve it using a program like Python or Matlab, let me know the steps I need to take.

Thank you in advance.

$$
\ \\
\textbf{Equations} \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -w \ \cdot \ u \\
$$
$$
\frac{dw}{dx} = -w \ \cdot \ u\\
\ \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
\ \\
\textbf{Solutions} \\
\rule{8cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
u(x,t) = u_{\ 0} \cdot\big[1-e^{-u_{\ 0}\cdot x}+e^{-u_{\ 0}\cdot x \ + \ w_{\ 0}\cdot t}\big]^{-1}\\
w(x,t) = [w_{\ 0} \cdot e^{-u_{\ 0}\cdot x \ + \ w_{\ 0}\cdot t}]\cdot \big[1-e^{-u_{\ 0}\cdot x}+e^{-u_{\ 0}\cdot x \ + \ w_{\ 0}\cdot t}\big]^{-1}
$$
$$
\rule{11cm}{0.4pt} \\
\ \\
\ \\
\textbf{Boundary $$ Conditions} \\
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
u(x,0) = u_0 \\
w(0,t) = w_0 \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,t) = 0 \\
\ \\
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
\ \\
$$

Comment: I recently found about the "double laplace transform", I'm not sure it could be useful in your case but I would try digging in that direction first.

Comment: The paper might have mistakes. By the way, dots are not needed because there are no vectors here, but that is not an error. First, there is no ODE here so the straight
d's in the $w$ equation ought to be curly. Second, the 3rd and 4th boundary values are not taken by the proposed solutions, although the first two are. Third, the proposed solutions seem to satisfy only the $u$ equation and not the $w$ equation.